# Expanding a text box to fill the space available for it

Tags: html, css

I've got approximately this layout code:

```
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something!" class="form-control" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" />
</div>
```

```
.form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input[type="text"] {
  display: inline;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input[type="text"] {
  display: inline;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something!" class="form-control" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-default" />
</div>
```

I would like the button to be on the same line as the text box. But the default width of the text box is `100%`, and that pushes the button to the next line. How can I get the text box to expand to be as big as possible without doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you can specify the width of the button and let the text input grow and fill the space. The downside is it's a CSS3 feature and therefore not supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-width for text input

`max-width: 430px;` and button width   `width: 70px;` to adjust with container form
You can also use percentage width;

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nnwbLwu6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this. Best is to give the text box and the button percentage widths. First get rid of the negative margin on the submit button. Then add these styles:

```
.form input[type="text"] {
    width:80%;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
    width:17%;
}
```

The reason for the missing 3% is that buttons in particular in forms have a lot of extra style rules applied that add things like border and padding, and they differ depending on your browser.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwspuy03/)**